# Why does my divisors function not work in certain cases?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, division, factors

I have written this short function to calculate the number of factors a number has as a part of my program, however I have noticed that it does not work in certain cases.

Here is my code:

```
def divisors(n):
number_of_factors = 0

max_test_num = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))+1)
for i in xrange(1,max_test_num):
    if n%i ==0:
        number_of_factors += 2
    if i*i == n:
        number_of_factors -= 1
return number_of_factors
```

Now if the number has a pair of divisors which are coprime, then the result returned is 2 too big.

For example, with input as 20, it returns 8, when the correct answer is 6.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or simply a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max_test_num = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))+1)
```

This makes you count elements twice, for example, with 20: `ceil(sqrt(20))+1 = 5`, so the condition `if n%i ==0` applies for both 4 and 5, and for each you increase by 2.

The +1 in the mentioned line is redundant, remove it.

Comment: So simply remove the +1 and it will work for any case?

Comment: @ali yes. just remove it, the ceil(n)+1 is redundant, because if there is an element that it divides, you already discovered it

Comment: Ah okay, turned out to be a trivial problem, should've spotted that. Thanks for the help!